# VS2013 - Error with multiple includes of same header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

While porting a project from Visual Studio 2005 to 2013, I came across this strange behaviour for which I cannot find an explanation. The context was about creating template specializations by including a certain header file multiple times, but changing preprocessor definitions before each include to basically generate a different class declaration.

I could narrow down the issue to the following situation:

**gen.hpp**

```
#ifdef ENABLE_GEN

#ifdef GEN_SWAP_ORDER // (1)
   class Foo {};
#else
   class Bar {};
#endif

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#define ENABLE_GEN

#include "gen.hpp"
#define GEN_SWAP_ORDER
#include "gen.hpp"

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   Bar bar;
}
```

This works as expected, i.e. both `Foo` and `Bar` are declared and usable in `main()`.

Now, to cause the issue, change the `#ifdef` in the line marked by (1) to `#ifndef`, which should effectively only cause the order in which `Foo` and `Bar` are declared to be swapped. But instead, compilation then fails:

```
1>c:\path\to\main.cpp(10): error C2065: 'Bar' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\path\to\main.cpp(10): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'bar'
1>c:\path\to\main.cpp(10): error C2065: 'bar' : undeclared identifier
```

The preprocessed file looks like this (stripped some whitespace):

```
#line 1 "c:\\path\\to\\main.cpp"

#line 1 "c:\\path\\to\\gen.hpp"

   class Foo {};

#line 8 "c:\\path\\to\\gen.hpp"

#line 10 "c:\\path\\to\\gen.hpp"
#line 4 "c:\\path\\to\\main.cpp"

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   Bar bar;
}
```

My question is: Am I missing something? Is this expected behaviour for some reason? Is it a compiler setting/bug that makes Visual Studio skip the header contents (including the `#else` part) a second time when it thinks it has a header guard (because of the `#ifndef`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen even when you do a full clean + rebuild (to rule out precompiled header shenanigans)?

Comment: Visual Studio contains optimizations for include guards, maybe they're buggy? There has been a pre-release bug that seems similar: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800200/preprocessing-broken-in-vs2013

Comment: Zinger, they didn't fix that bug completely.  Visible with /showIncludes, you'll see the file only getting #included once.

Comment: I cannot repro this with either Visual C++ 2013 RTM (18.00.21005.01) or Update 3 (18.00.30723.00).

Comment: @Cameron Yes, it does still happen.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis It happens on Update 2 as well as the VS2015 pre-release, so it would be strange if it was fixed in Update 3.

Comment: I immediately reproduced it with VS Express 2013 for Desktop Update 4. There's no such problem in VS 2012.

Comment: My apologies; I misread your question and failed to note that I needed to change the `#ifdef` to an `#ifndef` to repro the problem.  I've reactivated the Connect bug and notified our compiler team.  Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: Thank you. I should have used the problematic code directly in the example to avoid this confusion. Also, should this be in an answer which I can mark as accepted?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis -- do you want to post an answer for this? If not, I can community-wiki something for you, or ask Dienes to answer his own question :)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis -- CWTFY (Community Wiki'd That For You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [MS Connect issue 800200](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800200/preprocessing-broken-in-vs2013) as per dyp's comment, and was fixed in VS2013 RTM.